# Material UI , Next12, React 18

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to try out the latest version of NextJS(version 12) to give my project access to SSR ServerComponents & Http streaming.

MaterialUI works fine with Next 12.0.7 and React 17 (installed using npx create-next-app@latest)

When I do

`npm install react@beta react-dom@beta`

Then

`npm install @mui/material @mui/styled-engine-sc styled-components --save`

Gives

```
(base) marcfielding@MBP meta-ui % npm install @mui/material @mui/styled-engine-sc styled-components --save

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: meta-ui@undefined
npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0-rc.0-next-f2a59df48-20211208
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0-beta-24dd07bd2-20211208" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.2" from @mui/material@5.2.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!   @mui/material@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/marcfielding/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/marcfielding/.npm/_logs/2021-12-09T16_48_20_688Z-debug.log
```

Is this just a wait for MUI to catch up? Or is there a release I can install I was following the instructions from [here](https://mui.com/getting-started/installation/) previously?

Comment: @Summer's answer below is pretty valid. NPM@7 has a wacky peer dependency resolution system, you can read here a bit more http://ostack.cn/?qa=538022/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't mind using yarn, here is a repo you can fork with the deps you want: https://github.com/MiniDeathStar/material-ui-next12-react-18

If you want to use npm, you can run:

```
npm install @mui/material @mui/styled-engine-sc styled-components --legacy-peer-deps
```

[Mui shouldn't be broken by React@18](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/milestone/45). I've used them together just fine. Npm is a finicky package manager though, so I'll advocate for Yarn 3 whenever I get the chance.

Comment: Heya Summer, thanks for this and apologies for the slow reply - I'm back at my desk today and will test this out, thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't worry about the bounty expiring, I'll still sort it for you - just been crazy busy first day back at work, I will get to it shortly :-)

Comment: Heya, so Yarn was the way I got this to work, might be worth editing this answer to reflect that, sorry being slow - been afk for a while. I'm pretty sure I just did YARN install rather than anything special

Comment: @MrkFldig Glad it worked! Was it classic Yarn or Yarn v3? The NextJS version when I wrote the answer wasn't compatible with Yarn 3's PnP feature, so I had to set the nodeLinker to node-modules. I didn't feel like writing this much detailed instructions, so I just made a repo instead. Classic yarn doesn't use PnP so it would've worked out of the box. But current NextJS version (12.1) supports PnP so Yarn 3 now works out of the box, too.

Comment: You know what I can't remember but I am literally about to spinup a greenfield project so I'll come back to you shortly!