# Why Is Mui No Longer Installing?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use mui select in my React App. After using

```
npx create-react-app .
```

I then use

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

to install mui.

After following the steps to install Mui I am getting this error:

```
Could not resolve following dependency: peer react@"^17.0.0" from @mui/material@5.5.3
```

but it is apparently installed in the package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
..
    "react": "^18.0.0",
..
}
```

If anyone could help me figure out what's going on here, I'd sure appreciate it.

Comment: Give it a try with yarn

Answer (score 1):

MUI seems to be not ready for React Version 18.
The error message says, that Material UI Version `5.5.3` (which is the latest as of 2022-03-31) needs React with major version number 17 as peer dependency.

I hope someone has a better answer, but as of now it seems that we have to wait until the version number of React as peer dependency gets bumped to 18.0.0.

[Current progress of the MUI project](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/milestone/45)

Edit: following this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70548151/12340466) you should be able to get it working by using the `--legacy-peer-deps` flag

```
npx create-react-app test
cd test
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled --legacy-peer-deps
```

Answer (score 0):

Try vite, or try again :), by now it's resolved.
I added axios, sass, react-router-dom, @reduxjs/toolkit as well. 
this is a good start after creating a brand new react app.

```html
npm i sass axios react-router-dom @reduxjs/toolkit react-redux @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```